# django inserting into Oracle database invalid identifier

Tags: python, django, oracle, insert

Trying to insert data into my table on my database with Django. This is my model for the Table I'm trying to insert into:

```
class RunableFilters(models.Model):
    equipment_id = models.BigIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    filter_file_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    last_updated = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'runable_filters'
```

error I get:

```
>>> from books.models import RunableFilters
>>> p1 = RunableFilters(equipment_id = '123456778', filter_file_name = "test_file_name", last_updated = "2013-16-8")
>>> p1.save()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 546, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 650, in save_base
    result = manager._insert([self], fields=fields, return_id=update_pk, using=using, raw=raw)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 215, in _insert
    return insert_query(self.model, objs, fields, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1675, in insert_query
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 937, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\util.py", line 41, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\oracle\base.py", line 717, in execute
    six.reraise(utils.DatabaseError, utils.DatabaseError(*tuple(e.args)), sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\oracle\base.py", line 710, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, self._param_generator(params))
DatabaseError: ORA-00904: "RUNABLE_FILTERS"."ID": invalid identifier
```

Thats the table in my DB

[image]

Comment: running python 32bit 2.7 and django 1.5.2

Comment: Was that db created by django's `syncdb` command? If not, show us your table schema.

Comment: that DB was a legacy DB and was alrady created and structured along with the RunableFilters table, I ran the inspectdb to create the Model for the table.. added the schema for the table

Comment: that is the problem, django expects a PK field named `id`, you can solve it easily, learn about integrate legacy databases: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/legacy-databases/ .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is the problem, django expects a PK field named `id`

You can solve it easily, learn about integrate legacy databases: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/legacy-databases/ .

For your code, locate primary key and inform django for it. Le'ts supose `equipment_id` can act as pk:

```
class RunableFilters(models.Model):
    equipment_id = models.BigIntegerField( primary_key=True)  #<-- here
    filter_file_name = models.CharField(max_length=255,  ...
```

If you have a composite pk, then, read this post: https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/MultipleColumnPrimaryKeys

Comment: literally just tried adding equipment_id as primary key and it worked right before I checked this. Was about to write an answer. Thank you for the help